# Create PreparedStatement from statement?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

This is going to sound a little bit weird but I want to create a `PreparedStatement`
after I have a `Statement` . This is because my project is almost 50% , and until now 
I've used a `Statement` .

In my Database class I have a constructor that connects to mysql every time that I need to use the Mysql server :

```
public class Database 
{
    private Statement m_statement = null;
    private Connection m_connection = null;
    private PreparedStatement m_prepared = null;  // that one was added just now 

    private static final String ACCOUNTS_TABLE = "CheckingAccountsTable";
    private static final String PERSONNEL_TABLE = "PersonnelTable";
    // private static final String 


    public Database() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            this.m_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost","root","root");
            this.m_statement = this.m_connection.createStatement();

        }

        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed! 2!");
        }

    }


}




// from here I have something like 20 methods that are based on the Statement
```

Changing everything would require a lot time that I don't have . So ,my question is :

Can I use the Statement that I created with the `PreparedStatement` ? or create  `PreparedStatement` based on `Statement` ?

Thanks

Comment: Statement created with a preparedstatement? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `Statement` and `PreparedStatement` represent different things.

- `Statement` is used to call different SQL queries, you create a `Statement` instance without knowing what SQL query you are going to use.
- `PreparedStatement` is given a SQL query at the time it is created, and the driver tries to precompile the query, if possible. You can fill in different parameters and use it repeatedly, but you cannot change the query, it always uses the one given at its creation time.

So I'm afraid you'll have to refactor your code, there is no simple way how to switch between these two.

In most cases, using `PreparedStatement` is much preferred, as it allows you pass parameters to a SQL query in a safe way, without risking [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).